# How can I compress images with DropzoneJS?

Tags: javascript, image, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am currently attempting to compress images using DropzoneJS. I'd like to compress the images by quality, removing metadata, etc. and not just by resizing. How can I do it?

Comment: Define `compress`? Dropzone is a file upload lib with nice UI. It has options for resizing the images ... is that what you mean? If so read https://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration

Comment: I do not want to resize the image.  I want to compress the file by reducing the filesize, such as removing metadata, reducing the quality, etc.

Comment: You could handle the transform event https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-transformFile but again this is not something that DropzoneJs does for you out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. You will need the image compressing library, which can be downloaded here: https://xkeshi.github.io/image-compressor/

```
// "myDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  transformFile: function(file, done) {
     const imageCompressor = new ImageCompressor();

     imageCompressor.compress(file, {
     // I assume the output image won't have the meta data anymore
     checkOrientation: true,
     // Limit output image width & height
     // For controllable file size & avoid blank output image
     // https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor#maxwidth
     maxWidth: 8192,
     maxHeight: 8192,
     // 0.8 is the default and already good enough
     // https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor#quality
     quality: 0.6,
     // Convert ALL PNG images to JPEG
     convertSize: 0,
     })
     .then((result) => {
       // Handle the compressed image file.
       done(result)
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       // Handle the error
       throw err
     })
  }
};
```

Comment: The link is broken. Does anyone have the working one?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it's this library: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/compressorjs

Comment: Its https://npmjs.com/package/@xkeshi/image-compressor and its deprecated